# Comparing mixed types to establish canonical order in array

Tags: php, arrays

**Is this a good way to do this? If not what do you recommend?**

The order is irrelevant as long as it is consistent. I also already know the values are not equal.

```
//We cannot know what types of data will be found here except that it is not a resource.
$element_array = [
   $any_type_but_resource1,
   $any_type_but_resource2,
   $any_type_but_resource3,
   $any_type_but_resource4,
   $any_type_but_resource5,
   $any_type_but_resource6
]
```

My initial solution: Serialize the values and use strcmp() but ensure that 0 can never be returned.

```
usort($element_array, static function($a, $b){
    return strcmp(serialize($a), serialize($b));  
 );
```

You can see here https://3v4l.org/vRB65 that my sort works while the sort() does not. Does anyone have reason to suspect this will not always work?

Comment: Anything wrong with just `sort()`?

Comment: `sha1()` requires the passed argument to be a string (or something that can be automatically cast to one) so this won't work with arrays or objects that don't implement `__toString()`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky That is a great point. I've replaced sha1 with serialize.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm somewhat suspicious of the generic sort function when it will be comparing different types. It seems like it could be likely to fail to sort.

Comment: Your only requirement is that the sorting has to be consistent, `sort()` would satisfy that requirement. Your question is beginning to seem unanswerable because it feels like you have a hidden agenda.

Comment: If you can prove the shortcomings of `sort()` then this discussion would be a lot more useful. Right now it's a wild goose chase.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus The php manual states: 
Warning: Be careful when sorting arrays with mixed types values because sort() can produce unexpected results, if sort_flags is SORT_REGULAR,
Since the sort() function can fail according to the manual. I'm concerned that unexpected circumstances when comparing mixed types could create a situation where it does.
Also, none of the other flags are appropriate for mix comparisons.

Comment: If that can help: https://3v4l.org/7Wa3Y. Unless I misunderstood the question, `sort` wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: Also, not sure why you feel the need to test for 0 and return 1. If you know in advance the values are gonna be different, comparing their serialization should never return 0 anyway, right?

Comment: Thanks @Jeto, this is basically what I expected with sort() and why I felt I needed a more robust solution. The comparison method is questionable with objects or mixed types. Interestingly the sort function thinks it was successful. https://3v4l.org/Ks3fr

Comment: @Jeto That should be removed. I was using a hash before I realized I still had to convert to string first and wanted no chance of collision. Can you think of any reasons why this would be a bad way to do this?

Comment: your `if($result === 0 ){return 1;}` code will potentially cause `usort` to fail as it is quite possible that during its operation it will call your sort function with the same values more than once, but sometimes as `$a, $b` and sometimes as `$b,$a`. Adding that code will then give an inconsistent result for the same values.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I have removed it. That is a great point. The question has been updated.